# Use of monotone convergence on negative function?

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, potential-theory

I am reading a proof in Ransford's *Potential Theory in the Complex Plane*, where he uses the monotone convergence theorem on a negative function, and I do not understand why he can do that.

It is stated that for $m \geq 1$ and a compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb{C}$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
 \int_K \int_K \max(\log|z-w|,-m)\,d \mu (z) d \mu (w) \to \int_K \int_K  \log|z-w|\,d \mu (z) d \mu (w),
\end{eqnarray*} for $m \to \infty$, since $\max(\log|z-w|,-m) \to \log|z-w|$ for $m \to \infty$.

Can someone help me to see why this is possible?

Comment: Look at the negative of the integral and remember that $\int-f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=-\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$. That is, consider $\max(\log|z-w|,-m)=-\min(-\log|z-w|,m)$, where $\min(-\log|z-w|,m)$ increases monotonically in $m$.

Comment: @robjohn: uh that's a nice trick, but I'm not sure I completely get it, $\min(-\log|z-w|,m)$ can still be negative?

Comment: For each fixed $z-w$, how does the sequence $f_m(z-w)=\max(-m,\log(|z-w|))$ behave as $m$ increases?

Comment: The part of the integral where $\log|z-w|\gt0$ is always there; it needs to converge for any $m$ since the functions of the sequence are integrable. We can separate out that part and only concentrate on the part where $\log|z-w|\le0$ and we can apply Monotone convergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence of functions, $\min(-\log|z-w|,m)$ increases in $m$. Monotone convergence applies to them.

The integrals in the question are the negatives of the integrals of these functions.

---

**Considerations from Comments**

We are looking for
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{m\to\infty}\int_K\int_K\max\left(\log|z-w|,-m\right)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(z)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(w)\\
&=-\lim_{m\to\infty}\int_K\int_K\min\left(-\log|z-w|,m\right)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(z)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(w)\\
&=-\lim_{m\to\infty}\int_K\int_K[|z-w|\gt1]\min\left(-\log|z-w|,m\right)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(z)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(w)\\
&\phantom{\,=\,}-\lim_{m\to\infty}\int_K\int_K[|z-w|\le1]\min\left(-\log|z-w|,m\right)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(z)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(w)\\
&=\color{#090}{\int_K\int_K[|z-w|\gt1]\log|z-w|\,\mathrm{d}\mu(z)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(w)}\\
&\phantom{\,=\,}-\color{#C00}{\lim_{m\to\infty}\int_K\int_K[|z-w|\le1]\min\left(-\log|z-w|,m\right)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(z)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(w)}\\
\end{align}
$$
The green integral must converge if the integrals converge for any $m$. In fact, the green integral is the $m=0$ integral in the sequence. The red integral is a monotonically increasing sequence of non-negative functions; thus, we can apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Thanks you for your excellent answer! It get it now